# PrimeFaces Tree Table with context menu

Tags: jsf, jsf-2, primefaces

I have a PrimeFaces tree table with context menu but no action or action listener is executed, when I click on a context menu item.

Here is a fragment of my code:

```
<h:form id="formHistoriaUsuario">
    <p:commandButton id="nuevo"
                     value="#{msg['historiaUsuario.nuevo']}"
                     icon="ui-icon-document"
                     action="#{historiaUsuarioControlador.nuevo}"
                     update=":panelNuevaHistoriaUsuario"/>
    <p:contextMenu id="menuHistoria" for="tablaHistoriasUsuario" nodeType="historia">
        <p:menuitem value="Nueva Tarea" update=":panelNuevaTarea"
                    actionListener="#{historiaUsuarioControlador.nuevaTarea}"
                    oncomplete="PF('dlgTarea').show()"
                    icon="ui-icon-document"/>
        <p:menuitem value="#{msg['generico.etiquetas.editar']}"
                    icon="ui-icon-pencil"
                    action="#{historiaUsuarioControlador.editar}"/>
    </p:contextMenu>
    <p:contextMenu id="menuTarea" for="tablaHistoriasUsuario" nodeType="tarea">
        <p:menuitem value="Editar" icon="ui-icon-pencil"/>
    </p:contextMenu>

    <p:treeTable value="#{historiaUsuarioControlador.root}" var="historia"
                 id="tablaHistoriasUsuario"
                 selectionMode="single"
                 emptyMessage="#{msg['generico.datatable.vacia']}"
                 selection="#{historiaUsuarioControlador.historiaUsuarioSeleccionada}">
        <f:facet name="header">
            Historias de Usuario 
        </f:facet>
        <p:column headerText="#{msg['historiaUsuario.codigo']}"
                    style="text-align: center; width: 100px">
            <h:outputText value="#{historia.codigo}"/>
        </p:column>
        ....
    </p:treeTable>
</h:form>
```

I can't find a solution, some help would be appreciated

Also the first button stop working.